# how to register a tag in HTML django to make a string lowercase?

Tags: python, django, tags

I have a python list, iterated over to display a bullet point list on a web page. I want to make each entry in the list lower case, but still keep the original case for what get's displayed.

I'm getting the following warning via Django below:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'catEntry', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

My html:

```
{% extends "cats/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    cats
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All cats</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
        {% newEntry= entry.lower() %} 
            <li><a href = 'cats/{{newEntry}}.md' </a>{{ entry }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#lower but you should use a CSS class in my opinion.

Comment: Also note this is not called "registering a tag"; it's "using a filter". What you thought you had to do was "creating a variable". Be careful in the words you choose.

Comment: ok thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% filter force_escape|lower %}
    This text will be HTML-escaped, and will appear in all lowercase.
{% endfilter %}
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Thanks @Hello World. rather than displaying the HTML in lowercase, I'm hoping that the variable that gets passed into the hyperlink is lowercase ....

Comment: @KatieMelosto but if you want the variable to be lowercase then why not set the variable to be lowercase

Comment: I would like it to display in its original case on the web page, but when it opens the hyperlink, it seems like it needs to all be lowercase. Is there a way to make a new variable in HTML using Django equal to the old variable in lowercase [sorry. I'm quite new to Django!)

Comment: @KatieMelosto I don't know what you mean by old variable, have you tried with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Similar to your comment above I just changed one line: ```<li><a href = 'cat/{{entry | lower}}' </a>{{ entry }}</li>```

Comment: @KatieMelosto glad I helped :)